# No. of rows that can be written using SXSSF Workbook

Tags: java, xlsx

What is the maximum number of rows that can be written to a .xlsx file using SXSSFWorkbook?

Comment: The number of Rows in Excel itself is limited to 1048576 which could be stored in exaclty 20 bits

Comment: I want to know how many rows a sxxsf workbook can handle

Answer (score 2):

Just trying it with a dummy programm, it seems to be possible to write into row #1048576 (2^20) which is the last row on a Office 2010 Excel sheet.

After further trying, it is obvious that 500k rows are no problem. It just depends on your RAM if you want to write more (up to the limit of the 2^20 rows)